# Jquery - Add parent class to link in child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a Chrome extension for a forum. Here is a piece of HTML from a thread-page:

```
<div class="body_message" data-message-id="198342" data-topic-id="2876" data-user-id="1769">
    <div class="uk-grid post_wrapper">
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-6">
            <div class="poster"> 
                <h4></h4>
                <ul class="reset smalltext" id="msg_198342_extra_info">
                    <li class="postcount">194</li>
                    <li class="online">Online:</li>
                    <li class="profile"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I add buttons (img0, img1, img2, img3) to each post:

```
$("li.profile").before("<li class='verdacht smalltext'>Verdenking: "+img0 + img1 + img2 + img3 +"</li>");
```

Now those buttons need to trigger a function, and send the data-user-id along. When a button is clicked, all posts from that user will get a different background color.

Any idea on how to get the parents 'data-user-id', within each post?

Comment: `$(selecteor).parent().attr("data-user-id")` ?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `closest()` is your friend here.It traverses the selectors ancestors and returns the first matched element.

```
var userId = $('.profile').closest('.body_message').data('user-id');
```

Comment: And i guess i need to loop between the different posts with an each-loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse up the dom from the element that fired the event (`this`) to the closest `<div class="body-message">` and get the `data-user-id` value using jQuery's `data()` function.

```
// assuming img0 is a jQuery object
img0.on('click',function(e){
    var data = $(this).closest('.body_message').data('user-id');
    // do whatever you need in the click event
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work, thanks to your suggestions!

```
$( "li.profile" ).each(function() {
    var userId = $(this).closest('.body_message').data('user-id');
    $(this).before("<li class='verdacht smalltext'>Verdenking: "+img0 + img1 + img2 + img3 + userId +"</li>");
});
```

Next thing to figure out is the Chrome storage..